# How to share just part of the IntelliJ settings repository?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm testing out the Setting Repository feature, but we only want to share certain settings. Specifically, codestyles and inspections. Near as I can tell so far in playing with it, you have to share everything or nothing.

But everyone has their own keymaps and color scheme, we don't want to share those bits.

Is there a way to configure this IntelliJ feature to share just selected portions of the settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scheme for your project by selecting "Project" in the Code Style configuration:

[image: Code Style Settings]

When doing that, a "Project" code style file will be generated in your project tree:

[image: Project.xml file]

You can add this file to your VCS, like Git. And everyone working with you will be able have the same settings for Code Style.